# Trying to clone SecondaryBuffer but got an MemoryAccessViolation exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, clone, directsound

I'm trying to clone `SecondaryBuffer` so I can play the same sound multiple times at the same time.

this is the code I'm using:
In the main thread:

```
Device sounddevice = new Device();
sounddevice.SetCooperativeLevel(this, CooperativeLevel.Normal);

BufferDescription description = new BufferDescription();
description.ControlEffects = false;

SecondaryBuffer buffer = new SecondaryBuffer(file, description, sounddevice);
```

In a function running on different thread:

```
SecondaryBuffer buffer2 = buffer.Clone(sounddevice);
buffer2.Play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Default);
```

this is the exception I got on the `Clone` function:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Anyone got a solution for that?

Comment: @Daniel: Does this problem still happening if you do the Clone on the same thread?